# How to format rounding in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function round(a, b, c) {
  var roundformat = c
  var d = a / b
  var result = Math.round(d)
  console.log(result)
}
```

For example I want to rounding then format the number based on arguments c:

```
 If c = 4
 Output is: 5,3333
 If c = 2 
 Output is: 5,33
```

Comment: [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score -1):

```
function round(a, b, c) {
      var d = a / b;
      var result = d.toFixed(c);
      console.log(result);
    }
    round(8, 3, 3);
```